# How to call a web methods from another project

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a web service running on another instance of Visual Studio 2010,
i have added my service to another project.
how do i call and send data from the service that has been added to the new project?

The web method in the service accepts 2 strings.

Comment: consume that web service to the project in which you want to use that method 

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8257/How-to-make-a-simple-WebService-and-consume-it


http://computer.financialexpress.com/20030901/techspace02.shtml

Comment: You need to learn about how to create and/or consume web services. This link is one such kind to learn..  http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/062602-1.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You have search How to Consume Webservice to other project. For Example if you are running your webservice in your system, it will give you URL like this

```
http://localhost:54808/WebSite4/Service.asmx

http://127.0.0.1/WebSite4/Service.asmx
```

If you want to consume your `webservice` to other project you have to host your `webservice` or you need to have webserver to do this.

to consume your `webservice` you have to use Your system Network IP address

Example:

```
http://192.2.0.1/WebSite4/Service.asmx
```

by using this URL ,you can consume it in any other project according to you convenient.

I hope it will you.

Have a nice day

Comment: Thanks guys got it working. i just moved from winForms to web, its all new to me.

Answer (score 0):

[http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/84c85b/net-web-services/][1][enter link description here][1]

[1]: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/34279-introduction-to-web-services-in-c#/once go through it i guess will help full to you

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're a newb, some things you might want to know

wcf webservices produce XML and have metadata
 the internet is all about Json, which is unstructured data

you should learn about webApi or [Rest using WCF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/167159/How-to-create-a-JSON-WCF-RESTful-Service-in-60-sec),

if you wish to use DataContracts and Structured data but send Json what I do is have a main class that includes properties of all the classes my Service exposes, and send it as xml. then use AddWebReference to add the web reference to my project. the reference arrives with all the data contracts. pretty neat.